# How to create a list view as a part of a form in android

Tags: android

How to create a `ListView` as a part of a form in Android using `ListView` as a part of the form something similar to select option in `html` is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) for this purpose.